# Proving the limit, as x->2, for x^2=4, with intervals (but without possible circular reasoning)

Tags: limits, epsilon-delta

On page 200 (pg 208 on pdf) of the **OpenStax** Calculus, after solving the $\delta$, I'm wondering if it's circular reasoning to use $x^2$ in a proof that involves $x^2$ itself.

Although I know how to do $\epsilon-\delta$ limits with absolute values (usually with $\lim_{x \to 2} x^2 = 4$, we'd bound $\delta \leq 1$ and so eventually get $\delta = \min\{1,\frac{\epsilon}{5}\}$) I want to also try it with intervals and see if I can figure out the proof that way.

I can get up to the point where
$$-(2-\sqrt{4-\epsilon})<x-2<\sqrt{4+\epsilon}-2$$
$$-\delta<x-a<\delta$$
Where the leftmost expression is the $\delta$ (on the left) and the rightmost expression is the $\delta$ (on the right). So I can find the $\delta$'s, but I'm not sure how to show that these $\delta$'s indicate that $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$ using intervals.

Link to book: https://d3bxy9euw4e147.cloudfront.net/oscms-prodcms/media/documents/CalculusVolume1-OP.pdf

Comment: It's not clear what step in the reasoning you find objectionable: why don't you try pointing out which step confuses you. Your remark about circularity makes no sense. If I want to prove "If $x^2=1$, then $x=1$ or $x=-1$," for example, I have to "use $x^2$" in the proof. Indeed, one proof goes as follows: if $x^2=1$, then $x^2-1=0$, so $(x-1)(x+1)=0$, so $x=1$ or $x=-1$. This proof "uses" $x^2$ to prove a statement that "involves $x^2$ itself." But there is nothing at all circular about it.

Comment: @Sat A minor point is that in your line of $-(2-\sqrt{4-\epsilon})<x-2<\sqrt{4+\epsilon}-2$, you have the $2$ terms on the left side mixed around.

Comment: "I'm wondering if it's circular reasoning to use x2 in a proof that involves x2 itself."  Why would that be circular? You aren't trying to define $x^2$ are to prove it exists.

Comment: $-(2-\sqrt{4-\epsilon})<x-2<\sqrt{4+\epsilon}-2$ so $\sqrt{4-\epsilon} < x < \sqrt{4+\epsilon}$.  Presuming that $\epsilon < 4$ we have $0 < \sqrt{4-\epsilon} < x < \sqrt{4+\epsilon}$.  We know that on positive numbers squaring preserves order so $4-\epsilon < x^2 < 4+\epsilon$ and $-\epsilon < x^2 -4 < \epsilon$.  There's nothing circular about that.  I'm not sure why you think that would be an issue.

Comment: Remember:  If $a < b$ and $c > 0$ then $ac < bc$.  So if $\sqrt{4-\epsilon}<x<\sqrt{4+\epsilon}$ then $\sqrt{4-\epsilon}*\sqrt{4-\epsilon}<x\sqrt{4-\epsilon} < x*x < x*\sqrt{4+\epsilon} < \sqrt{4+\epsilon}*\sqrt{4+\epsilon}$... So no problem.

Comment: The circular reasoning relates to Spivak (last question in chapter 5) In the answer book, "how do we know that $\sqrt{a^2-\epsilon}$ and $\sqrt{a^2+\epsilon}$ exist!? [Later] we prove that every positive number has a square root, but the proof of this theorem uses the fact that $f(x)=x^2$ is continuous, which is essentially what we are trying to prove. In fact, the existence of square roots is essentially equivalent to the continuity of $f$.

Comment: +1 for @Sat comment. In fact this is the only thing in Spivak's book which is sort of new.

Answer (score 1):

The plot below shows the curves of $2-\sqrt{4-\epsilon}$ (blue) and $\sqrt{4+\epsilon}-2$ (green) as well as $\dfrac \epsilon5$ (magenta).

It is clear that the green bound is tighter and could be used for the symmetric range, as does the linear, simpler expression.

[image]

There is no circular argument as the given expressions do not involve a limit, just a functional relation between $\epsilon$ and $\delta$.

Comment: How do you know that $\sqrt{4-\epsilon}$ and $\sqrt{4+\epsilon}$ exist? (The comment relates to my reply in the original question, which relates to a question and answer in Spivak's text)

Comment: @Sat: that's obvious on the plot and trivial to prove. Of course we switch to $\delta=1$ when appropriate. There is still no circular argument.